# Always Response 403 Using Python Requests Refresh Token

Tags: python, python-requests, refresh-token

```
curl -X POST https://myabc.net/oauth/token -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=my_client_id&client_secret=my_client_secret&refresh_token=my_refresh_token'
```

always works fine

I want to call it using Python requests but it keeps returning 403 response

```
body = {"grant_type":"refresh_token","client_id":"my_client_id","client_secret":"my_client_secret","refresh_token":"my_refresh_token"}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"application/json"}

requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body)) #--> 403 response.
```

--verbose from curl:

```
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x565031026600)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> POST /oauth/token HTTP/2
> Host: something.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 194
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Sun, 09 May 2021 23:40:21 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< set-cookie: __cfduid=d41356fb21ab4ae6232ba74a856c562aa1620603621; expires=Tue, 08-Jun-21 23:40:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.something.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< cache-control: private, no-store
< pragma: no-cache
< etag: W/"433085d4030f6e3ccf8f40bfb72402f5"
< x-request-id: 88c26688-c83d-43d6-91f2-56209db8a330
< x-runtime: 0.035997
< vary: Origin
< via: 1.1 google
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< cf-request-id: 09f519e83f000019185fbc5000000001
< expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< set-cookie: __cfruid=84b1b72128f47cbf976ee0ee03a1453c1744c389-1620603621; path=/; domain=.something.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 64cec5b9fa8d1918-SIN
```

while requests response.headers:

```
    {'Date': 'Sun, 09 May 2021 23:47:53 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; 
charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 
'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d7305f0dc828240a3bda07728ef49eb961620604073; 
expires=Tue, 08-Jun-21 23:47:53 GMT; path=/; domain=.something.com; 
HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax', 'cf-request-id': '09f520cf2200001a36f38ed000000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, 
report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 
'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 
'CF-RAY': '64ced0c50ec91a36-SIN', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

The source server uses Cloudflare..is this the issue? Can someone please point-out where the problem is? There is no enough documentation on owner's site

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send urlencoded data, You don't need to encode it, simply pass a dict as data parameter.

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm still getting 403. with/out header and passed pure dict as data. Can you please be specific with your answer by modifying the above code? Thx